# Minimum sample size for 1-tailed hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

Let's say we have some endangered species of animals, whose population is 10,000 and dwindling due to some disease they all carry. And say I want to be able to test the efficacy of some new drug (with an expected success rate of, say, 65%) vs. an old drug (which has a success rate of, say, 20%). What are the minimum sample sizes that I should pick for both the test and control groups such that I am able to establish a statistically significant result that the new drug is indeed better than the old one?

Comment: The answer to this type of question is to run a power analysis. To do so, you need to specify the alpha (type I error rate) you want to use (typically 5%), and how much power you want your study to have (80% is a common convention).

Comment: Let's say I specify those parameters. Does my answer then depend on assuming some particular distribution?

Comment: The success rate would be binomial if you knew the number of animals exposed to the disease. Realistically, you are unlikely to know that, so you need to use a count model such as Poisson, quasi-Poisson, or negative binomial.